# Excel - Direct excel formula to calculate sum of product of deviations from the mean for 2 arrays x & y (without squaring)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

Is there a direct excel formula to calculate sum of product of deviations from the mean for 2 arrays, x & y (without squaring)

Here is the formula: [image]

I already know how to use SUMPRODUCT to get the result.
SUMPRODUCT(rng1 - avg(rng1), rng2 - avg(rng2))

I want to know if there is a direct formula such as [SUMXMY2 function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumxmy2-function-9d144ac1-4d79-43de-b524-e2ecee23b299)
which gives the following sum :  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the short answer is 'no' - the nearest function is Covariance.P

[image]

according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/covariance-p-function-6f0e1e6d-956d-4e4b-9943-cfef0bf9edfc)

so you have to multiply by the number of data pairs in the range to get the answer you want e.g.

```
=COVARIANCE.P(A2:A6,B2:B6)*COUNT(A2:A6)
```

using the data in the above reference.

Looking at this in a bit more detail, the Sumproduct formula *produces incorrect results* if there are missing data items in one or both columns because it treats them as zeroes so should probably be deprecated unless the user is confident of having complete data.

To allow for missing values in either column, the formula above should be changed to:

```
=COVARIANCE.P(A2:A6,B2:B6)*COUNTIFS(A2:A6,"<>",B2:B6,"<>")
```

[image]